# NServiceBus endpoint writes to Azure, receiving endpoint cannot find record

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, nservicebus, messaging

I have the following scenario:

One endpoint handles a message and in that message handling writes a record to an Azure SQL DB. (This is a local in house endpoint). Directly after that, an event is published that this record has been saved.
A second endpoint receives that event and reads the record from the DB and does it's own thing. The first endpoint is transactional so it should be that both DB writes and event publishing should happen in the same transaction scope.

Now sometimes the problem occurs that the second endpoint does not find the record that by logic should be there. It fails in the FLR but manages to recover in the SLR.

This only happens on our production environment and only sometimes. I have tried to reproduce this locally without any success therefor I am a bit lost. Anybody faced a similar problem that could share some insight?

Answer (score 0):

What transport are you using? Are you using MSMQ on a Azure VM where the endpoint read/writes to a SQL Azure DB? I assume that this is the case here.

You mention that the first end-point is transactional. Your solution creates two separate transactions:

- Transaction that reads a message from the MSMQ queue
- Transaction that writes (inserts) to SQL Azure DB

These transactions are separate and *not* combined as SQL Azure cannot take part in a distributed transaction.

You have to make sure that you commit the SQL Azure DB transaction before the MSMQ transaction and that your end-point is processing idempotent messages.

It is unclear why the subscriber succeeds in SLR. That doesn't really makes sense. I can only assume that the DB transaction has not been committed yet when the event message is already sent so that the subscriber tries to read it before the data is committed.

I would suggest that you have the following breakdown:

- Receive messages
- Open DB connection
- Start DB transaction
- Write/insert DB record
- Commit DB transaction
- Publish event message

This makes sure that the event message cannot be processed by any subscriber before the data is committed.

This should not happen when the event is send in the same transaction as the original is read so pleas check that maybe transactions are disabled on the endpoint.

Comment: RabbitMQ is used as transport. I understand about having two transactions, and I suspect that the event is sent before the write is completed (that would explain the SLR succeeding). I checked the configuration of both endpoints and both have transactions enabled (busConfiguration.Transactions().Enable();). There is no additional transaction scope within the handlers and the publishing is done after the record is inserted in the DB. How can I commit to the DB before publishing the event?

Comment: When you use RabbitMQ then you do not have distributed transactions so be sure that the database actions are committed before you publish the event. You mention that you publish the event after the record insert so it should work. Are you using Entity Framework? Can you share how you create the database context and mention when `.SaveChanges()` is called on the context?

Comment: Dapper is used. So basically an IDbConnection instance is injected into the handler via StructureMap. With that instance and Dapper we insert records in the DB.